# WP - jquery works only on homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress

i'm calling an external js file with a bit of jQuery, a `$(document).ready` function which triggers on `mouseover`. The call is made in the footer.php, which is included in all of the theme's page (index.php, page.php etc).

The jQuery works fine on the homepage but doesn't seem to work on any other page. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any error coming up, can you track it down with firebug?

Comment: no error. tried firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you include jQuery? Using `enqueue_script()` ? If yes, WP include jQuery with noConflict activated. So you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: Btw, to avoid using `jQuery` every time, you can do this: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ your code here }` And use $ in `ready` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess things... have you tried moving the code from the footer into the `<head>`?